# Symfony - Api Platform : Edit object if statement on POST request

Tags: http, post, symfony4, put, api-platform.com

I use `API platform` with `Symfony5`, and I created a service to verify a statement if it is correct.

This statement if is correct, I want to change an existing object instead of adding on a POST request.

So, on POST request I created an event with `PRE_WRITE` events priorities, and this event calls a service who verifies if the statement is correct if is true, I edit an existing object.

All that work correctly without any problem, but the POST request is always for adding a new object, so, I get a new line on the database table.

Is there any solution, to return 200 responses on the edit object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a Response to the kernel.view event like:

```
....
public function yourEvent(Event $event)
{
   // do your service stuff
   // ...
   $event->setResponse(new Response('ok', 200));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `PUT` - for changes.

`POST`- to create a record